# View high score for a quiz with different difficulties in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a quiz with 3 difficulties: easy, medium and hard. I have a menu which allows the user to view high scores based on the difficulty they chose. I also need to make sure that if the user has done the quiz, and receives the high score, the user is told that they have achieved a high score. Is there a way I could do that?

This is my code for sorting high scores. The file looks like this:

```
2,adam,easy,2
4,john,hard,4
```

Is there a simpler way I could do that?

```
difficulty=input("Choose an option between easy/medium/hard: ")
     with open('quiz_scores.txt', "r") as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file)
     addressList=list(reader)
     addressList.sort(reverse=True)


 for details in addressList:
    if difficulty==details[2]:
        print(details)
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `pickle` or `json`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a list comprehension is enough?

```
difficulty = input("Choose an option between easy/medium/hard: ")
with open('quiz_scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = sorted(list(filter(lambda line: line.split(',')[2] == difficulty, f.readlines())))
    lines = reversed(lines) # python 3

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

If you are using Python 2, sort lines with

```
lines = sorted(list(filter(lambda line: line.split(',')[2] == difficulty, f.readlines())), reversed=True)
```

Comment: It doesent sort it highest to lowest though.

Comment: what does filter do?

Comment: To get score results with the specified difficulty, you can refer to [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) for how it works.